Making sense of certain vector-valued integrals in von Neumann algebra theory.
Let $M\subseteq B(H)$ be a von Neumann algebra and $\varphi$ a weight on $M$ with modular automorphism group $\{\sigma_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$.
We define
$M_\infty$ to be the set of all elements $m\in M$ for which the mapping
$$i\mathbb{R}\to M: it \mapsto \sigma_t(m)$$
has an entire analytic extension to a map
$\mathbb{C}\to B(H)$.
Question 1: Does the analytic extension have values in $M$ as well?
In a proof I am reading, it is claimed that
$M_\infty$ is strongly dense in $M$. To show this, the author defines for $x\in M$ the elements
$$x_n:= \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-nt^2} \sigma_t(x)dt.$$
The author then says "By strong continuity of $\{\sigma_t\}$ and the Lebesgue-dominated convergence theorem, we se see that $x_n\to x$ sot."
Question 2: How to make sense of these integrals? In what topology do these integrals converge?
Question 3: How is the Lebesgue-dominated convergence theorem applied to these integrals?
Thanks in advance for your help.

This is a partial answer that solves Questions $2$ and $3$. I’ll start with Question 2: these integrals converge in SOT. However, it might be conceptually cleaner to understand them as converging in the $\sigma$-weak topology, i.e., one may understand $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-nt^2} \sigma_t(x) \, dt$ as the element $\tilde{x} \in M = (M_\ast)^\ast$ defined by $\varphi(\tilde{x}) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-nt^2} \varphi(\sigma_t(x)) \, dt$ for all $\varphi \in M_\ast$.
Now, to understand the application of dominated convergence, we perform a change of variables $s = \sqrt{n}t$,
$$\varphi(x_n) = \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-nt^2} \varphi(\sigma_t(x)) \, dt =  \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s^2} \varphi(\sigma_{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}(x)) \, ds$$
Now, $|\varphi(\sigma_{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}(x))| \leq \|\varphi\|\|x\|$, so the integrand is bounded by $\|\varphi\|\|x\|e^{-s^2}$, which is integrable. SOT-continuity of $\{\sigma_t\}$ implies $\sigma_{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}(x) \to \sigma_0(x) = x$ in SOT as $n \to \infty$, for any fixed $s$. Thus, $\varphi(\sigma_{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}(x)) \to \varphi(x)$ for any fixed $s$, so by dominated convergence,
$$\varphi(x_n) \to \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s^2} \varphi(x) \, ds = \varphi(x)$$
This shows $x_n \to x$ $\sigma$-weakly. More or less the same method can be used to show the convergence in fact also happens in SOT. Since the difficulty is mainly just notational, I’ll leave that to you to check.

Thanks for this answer, but my answer is about the strong topology in specific. It is indeed clear that on the $\sigma$-weak level everything works nicely, but your answer does not adress why the SOT-integral exists, nor why the convergence also works in SOT. The same trick with functionals does not work here, I think.

@Andromeda It doesn’t. But by applying the integral to a vector in $H$, i.e., defining $\int e^{-nt^2} \sigma_t(x) , dt$ as the operator $\tilde{x}$ on $H$ with $\tilde{x}h = \int e^{-nt^2} \sigma_t(x)h , dt$ for all $h \in H$, the question reduces to an integral of a function with values in $H$, in which case this can be understood as a Bochner integral (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral).

@Andromeda Because Bochner integrals also satisfy dominated convergence theorem, everything in my answer basically carries through and shows SOT convergence. It’s just changing every application of $\varphi \in M_\ast$ to evaluation at $h \in H$. For this, you do have to know the basic theory of Bochner integrals, though.

Thanks. Making sense of this as Bochner integrals indeed does the trick. I am also pretty sure that it should be possible to look at this as being Riemann integrals, but then it is not clear how dominated convergence theorem should work without e.g. proving that the Riemann integral coincides with the Bochner integral.
